# Using custom role in QTreeView instead of DisplayRole

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt

A simple question, (hopefully with a simple answer).

QTreeView will pass Qt.DisplayRole to the model's data function when fetching rows for display, by default.
But say I wanted to pass 'MyAwesomeTreeDisplayRole' instead of Qt.DisplayRole, what would I need to do?
I can't seem to find anything about where the view decides to use displayrole or how to override it.

Just before you ask why I want to do such awful things..

Basically, my QAbstractItemModel is intended to be usable both for a treeview (1 column) and a tableview (multiple columns, based on parent).
Using the same DisplayRole for both types of views doesn't really work, since then I'm forced to return the same data for both. This results in me only seeing the first column in the treeview when I want to return a concatenation of a couple of columns.

I think the simplest way would be to just use custom roles (TreeDisplayRole and TableDisplayRole).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, how to do it in `python`, but you have to create your [own delegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html) to render items data. Delegate is actually the object, that requests any data from indices and renders it

Note, that in common case `QTreeView` *is able to show multiple columns*, you should only  have `columnCount` set <s>in</s>correctly for top-level index

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  I know TreeView can show multiple columns, but it seems to only set one global column count, so I'd have to set it to the size of my widest table and make some filler boilerplate to add empty columns to the node types that have less columns.  Also, 11 columns feels kind of awkward for a treeview. :P

Answer (score 0):

I've used QTreeView to view a simple table with many columns - it works well - you can adjust the column count by sending it the columnCountChanged signal.  So I'm not sure you need to do what you are asking.

But I've used ItemDelegates too: use my_treeview.setItemDelegate() to point the treeview to your item delegate.  If this subclasses QStyledItemDelegate then it doesn't need to do much work - it can mostly just pass it all through to super.

The user roles then are just agreed between your custom ItemDelegate and your ItemModel and can be anything you like as long as they are >= than QtCore.Qt.UserRole.

(Edit: Sorry, I put this in as a new answer but it's really just an elaboration on what Lol4t0 said - apart from the columnCountChanged thing)